# How much memory is reserved when initializing NSObject?

Tags: objective-c

When I use this statement in objective c

```
NSObject object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

How much memory is reserved for object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test the size of objects with the following code:

```
#import <malloc/malloc.h>
//...
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Size: %zd bytes", malloc_size((__bridge const void *)(obj)));
```

This test produced: "Size: 16 bytes"

Comment: and the answer this gives is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

According to Instruments, 16 bytes.  (Though, that's `NSObject *object = ...`)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on several factors, including whether you're on iOS or OS X, what OS version you've built against, and whether you're compiling 32-bit or 64-bit.  It's either 8 bytes or 16 bytes.  Basically it's 16 bytes, in more recent environments - there's a pointer to the class data structure, a reference count and four bytes of miscellaneous, class-specific data.

Note that the answer you get from malloc_size() will always be 16, because it returns the size of the allocation block, which may be larger than the actual size requested of malloc.  In OS X and iOS the allocation size is always at least 16 bytes.