# Subclass of NSObject - Its weight in terms of bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have the following NSObject subclass. How do I find the "weight" of it in terms of bytes? I understand that the pointer to this object is 16 bytes (I got that info from  [How much memory is reserved when initializing NSObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670185/how-much-memory-is-reserved-when-initializing-nsobject))

```
@interface PersonRecord : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *personName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personPhoneNumbers;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personPhoneNumberTypes;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personAddresses;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personAddressTypes;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personEmailIDs;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *personEmailIDTypes;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSData *personImageData;

@end
```

For example, NSString takes 1 byte, NSArray takes 'n' bytes etc. Is there a definitive way of calculating it?

My goal is to find if I collect 500 of these from the iPhone Address book inside NSArray, will it eat too much RAM of the iPhone.

Comment: Those are all pointers and hence take 8 bytes each on a 64-bit machine.  What I don't know is the "overhead" of an object -- 16 bytes sounds pretty light -- nor do I know what rounding may be applied to the size.

Comment: And, of course, the objects pointed to by these pointers take up space as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a 64-bit system, pointers are 8 bytes each, so we  can expect that your 8 properties (plus one for the isa defined in `NSObject`) to take up 72 bytes. On a 32-bit system, it'd take up half of that.

We can verify this with a handy method in the Objective-C runtime called [`class_getInstanceSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW38) that will tell us how "large" a single allocation of a class would be:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", class_getInstanceSize([PersonRecord class]));
```

As expected, this logs "72" on a 64-bit system, and "36" on a 32-bit system.

However, Hot Licks is right to point out that this is only the size of the pure `PersonRecord`. It does not include the size of the data pointed to by any of the properties. You could have only a single `PersonRecord` and yet still run out of memory, if you tried to load up hundreds of gigabytes into a string and put it into that `PersonRecord`'s `personName` field.

Before you go optimizing this object definition to try and squeeze every last byte that you can out of it, you should always measure your app first, and only optimize if and only if you have measured and have *proof* that there is a problem.

But... using back-of-the-envelope calculations, 500 of these is only 36,000 bytes, and if we estimate that each one of these 500 objects might be pointing to another 1,000 bytes of data, then we're looking at 536,000 bytes: less than half a megabyte of allocations. You're probably not going to have a problem with this. But again: MEASURE MEASURE MEASURE.

Comment: Your back of the envelope calculation is what I needed to hear.
You reminded me of my Algorithms-101 professor, who used to say the exact same words! :-D

Comment: Even if each object pointed to 10,000 bytes of data, then we're still only looking at about 5 megabytes of data. This still (probably) isn't going to be enough to break the memory bank :)

Comment: I suspect that getInstanceSize isn't reporting the overhead of the heap frame.  At minimum there needs to be a size and a reference count.  But these are probably regarded as "outside" the object proper.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, those are beyond the scope of the allocation proper. The reference count can get stored in a number of different places (sometimes compacted into the isa or in a global lookup table), so neither of those would count towards this size :)

Comment: And it's not clear that getInstanceSize will return the entire size for composite objects.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure what you mean. It says it returns "The size in bytes of instances of the class". So if you do `[TheClass alloc]`, it tells you how much space you allocated. Of course it's not going to tell you a "composite" size, because that's an implementation detail of the `-init*` methods.

Comment: I guess, in fact, I'm pointing out that getInstanceSize will grossly undercount things like NSMutableArray where a major part of the storage used is in the separately-allocated pointer array.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, you're absolutely right. `class_getInstanceSize` can be a bit of a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) for that reason.